# Error con Datetime al cambiar de pc

Tags: c#, datetime, parsear

Tengo una aplicación que realiza llamadas a través de una API, la cual responde un JSON con la información correspondiente.

En mi aplicación creo un objeto Datatable y creo tantas columnas como me devuelve el JSON.

```
var retorno = await EnviarGET<string>("Sinc...", "Get...", peticion, "GET");
DataTable tUsuarios = new DataTable();
JObject def = (JObject)JSON.ToObject(retorno);
JArray data = (JArray)JSON.ToObject(def["Datos"].ToString());

var oRetornoFichador = new JObject();
foreach (JObject item in data)
{
    DataColumn column;

    column = new DataColumn();
    column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    column.ColumnName = "Index";
    tUsuarios.Columns.Add(column);

    column = new DataColumn();
    column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime");
    column.ColumnName = "FechaDesde";
    tUsuarios.Columns.Add(column);

    column = new DataColumn();
    column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime");
    column.ColumnName = "FechaHasta";
    tUsuarios.Columns.Add(column);
    .
    .
    .
```

Como se ve, hay columnas de varios tipos, entre ellos DateTime.
Después de esto, creo una fila con la estructura de columnas de la tabla y la relleno con los datos del JSON:

```
foreach (JJSon.JObject item2 in data2)
{
    DataRow drow = tUsuarios.NewRow();

    Logger.Write(item2.ToString());

    if (item2["FechaDesde"].ToString() == "")
    {
        drow["FechaDesde"] = DateTime.Now;
    }
    else
    {
        Logger.Write(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString());
        drow["FechaDesde"] = DateTime.Parse(item2["FechaDesde"].ToString(), provider);
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

Mi problema está en esta línea (o similares que tengo más abajo):

```
drow["FechaDesde"] = DateTime.Parse(item2["FechaDesde"].ToString(), provider);
```

Cuando lo ejecuto en mi pc me funciona sin problema pero si lo ejecuto en otro pc me da un error:

***No se puede reconocer la cadena como valor DateTime válido.***

Creo que el error no es por el tipo de columna a la hora de hacer la asignación porque si intento imprimir ese mismo valor, sin meterlo a la tabla haciendo lo siguiente me da el mismo error:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES");
Logger.Write(DateTime.Parse(item2["FechaDesde"].ToString()).ToString());
```

He pensado que cambiando la Cultura me valdría pero en ambos equipos es "es-ES", esto lo veo con el logger.

Otra opción que he probado es a utilizar el método ParseExact de la clase DateTime indicando un formato y la cultura y me da el mismo error.

El json que contiene la fecha que me da problema es el siguiente:

```
{"Datos":
    [
        {
        .
        .
        .
        "FechaDesde":"27/11/2023 0:00:00",
        "FechaHasta":"01/01/2026 0:00:00",
        .
        .
        .
        }
    ]
}
```

Creo que el error no está en la Cultura utilizada porque la siguiente línea me la ejecuta sin problema en ambos pcs:

```
peticionGTPU.Add("diaFB", DateTime.Parse(f_blindaje).Day); //Valor de f_blindaje: "07/12/2023 17:07:45", es un string obtenido de un json
```

Comment: tienes que validar que lo datos que estas usando cumplen con los formatos... y esto es una practica que te ayudara en el futuro, en mi respuesta trato de abordar esa cultura. si bien tu formato de hora le falta un 0 no cumple con el formato HH que es el que esperas.

Comment: hay una solucion mucho mas simple. te importa la hora?

Comment: ¿La API es sensible a localización?

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover sospecho que es por eso, el resto de cosas ya no me cuadran, voy a mirar por ahí, gracias.

Comment: @gbianchi si, necesito la hora también, sospecho que me tendré que asegurar que la hora tenga 2 dígitos.

Comment: @Sal, en principio no.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes implementar CultureInfo como lo indican las otras dos respuesta, otra alternativa seria la siguiente:

```
using System.Globalization;

string fechaDesdeString = item2["FechaDesde"].ToString();
string formatoFecha = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fechaDesdeString))
{
    drow["FechaDesde"] = DateTime.Now;
}
else
{
    DateTime fechaDesde;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(fechaDesdeString, formatoFecha, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out fechaDesde))
    {
        drow["FechaDesde"] = fechaDesde;
    }
    else
    {
        // Manejar el caso en el que la cadena no pueda ser parseada como fecha
        Logger.Write("Error al parsear la fecha: " + fechaDesdeString);
    }
}
```

**Nota:** el enfoque debería ser más robusto y evitar problemas de interpretación de fechas al cambiar entre diferentes máquinas. Además, al utilizar `DateTime.TryParseExact`, puedes manejar posibles errores de parseo de manera más controlada.

No he tenido chance de probar el codigo en mi IDE, sujiero que lo tomes AS-IS.

**Update:**

Ahora algunos compañero hemos notado que el formato "27/11/2023 0:00:00" no lo podras evitar, para eso podemos extender un poco mas el manejo de formatos de fecha.

```
string fechaDesdeString = item2["FechaDesde"].ToString();
string[] formatosFechaHora = { "dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" };

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fechaDesdeString))
{
    drow["FechaDesde"] = DateTime.Now;
}
else
{
    DateTime fechaDesde;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(fechaDesdeString, formatosFechaHora, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out fechaDesde))
    {
        drow["FechaDesde"] = fechaDesde;
    }
    else
    {
        // Manejar el caso en el que la cadena no pueda ser parseada como fecha
        Logger.Write("Error al parsear la fecha: " + fechaDesdeString);
    }
}
```

Me acorde que algunos metodos de C# que trabajan con tipos char tambien aceptan arreglos de cadenas por eso es posible pasar el arreglo de formatos.

Comment: le hago upvote a este comentario porque por experiencia personal cuando tienes una fecha que tu no puedes manejar el formato en el que te llega lo mejor es verla con tus propios ojos y usar el formato que visualizas para hacer la conversion de texto a fecha con ese formato, esto te ahorra problemas

Comment: @LPZadkiel de acuerdo contigo

Comment: Gracias por el comentario @Francisco Nuñez IA Lover. He probado tu respuesta y no me funciona, me entra todo el rato al segundo else, no me convierte la fecha...

Comment: si entra al else no estas recibiendo ninguna de los formatos que indicas o no estas usando el último código.

Answer (score 1):

El primer problema es que una fecha debería transmitirse siempre en formato ISO ej: `2024-01-10T17:12:17.575Z`

Para convertir, según el formato que describes debes hacer:

```
var ci = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
var fecha = Convert.ToDateTime("27/11/2023 0:00:00", ci);
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el tipo de **cultura invariante**, el cual es **culture-insensitive**, se asocia con el idioma inglés pero no con ningún país/región.

```
drow["FechaDesde"] = DateTime.ParseExact(item2["FechaDesde"], "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvarianCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Se usa el **método ParseExact** el cual debe tener el mismo formato de la fecha que recibe como parámetro, caso contrario dará error.

Para poder usar la **clase CultureInfo** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Globalization;
```

**Nota**: Te recomiendo la respuesta de Francisco que está más completa.